# How to refer to other columns using a condition when creating a calculated column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

Suppose I have a SQL table as shown below where Min Spend is the minimum spend for each year and is a calculated column created using SQL-Window Function

```
|------------|-------|--------|----------|
|   Year     |Month  |  Spend |Min Spend |
|------------|-------|--------|----------|
|    2018    |   Jan |  10    |   10     |
|    2018    |   Feb |  20    |   10     |
|    2018    |   Oct |  25    |   10     |
|    2019    |   Jan |  90    |   45     |
|    2019    |   Aug |  60    |   45     |
|    2019    |   Nov |  45    |   45     |
|------------|-------|--------|----------|
```

I would like to create a new column as a calculated field in the table that gives me the month corresponding the the 'Min Spend' for that year as shown below

```
|------------|-------|--------|----------|---------------|
|   Year     |Month  |  Spend |Min Spend |Min Spend Month|
|------------|-------|--------|----------|---------------|
|    2018    |   Jan |  10    |   10     |   Jan         |
|    2018    |   Feb |  20    |   10     |   Jan         |
|    2018    |   Oct |  25    |   10     |   Jan         |
|    2019    |   Jan |  90    |   45     |   Nov         |
|    2019    |   Aug |  60    |   45     |   Nov         |
|    2019    |   Nov |  45    |   45     |   Nov         |
|------------|-------|--------|----------|---------------|
```

Can anybody suggest how to approach this?

Comment: Due to the preponderance of evidence, I removed the MySQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions like this:

```
select t.*,
       min(spend) over (partition by year) as min_spend,
       first_value(month) over (partition by year order by spend) as min_spend_month
from t;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon, what if two of the months in a year have equal Min Spend and I would require both in this case?

Comment: @ChinmoyJyotiKathar . . . I think that would be a different question and should be asked as a *new* question.  This question clearly has "month" in the singular.  Also, include your SQL Server version on that question.